# Hyperlink with Swing

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I have hyperlinks on my site made like that:

```
 <a href="#cennik">

 <a name="cennik"></a>
```

Now I want to add 'swing' effect to this link (Cause now after clicking it's just 'jumping'). I guess that It has to be done in Javascript but I have no idea how. My only guess is that it's animate() function maybe... Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use below code

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("#cennik").click(function(){
    $("#cennik").animate({height:"20px"},"slow","swing");
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

From there you can see that there's an easing option called "swing". If that's what you want then just configure the animation() method accordingly. For example:

```
$("#cennik").click(function(){
    $("cennik").animate({width:"200px"}, "slow", "swing");
});
```